# Spring - get field from list in model

Tags: spring, forms, hibernate, jsp, model-view-controller

I'm creating project with Spring + Hibernate, and I have a little problem:
I have entity `Hop`, and entity `Country`. When I'm adding new hop - through form, there is a `form:select` - choices for this list are from DB - this is the form:

```
<tr>
  <td><label>Origin:</label></td>
  <td>
    <form:select path="hopOrigin">
      <form:option value="" label="...." />
      <form:options items="${countryList}"/>
    </form:select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

To populate this list, I have this class in `HopController`:

```
@ModelAttribute("countryList")
    public List<Country> getCountry()   {

        List<Country> countriesNames = countryService.getCoutriesNames();

        return countriesNames;
    }
```

In the end, the country service is `@Autowired` to `CountryDaoImpl`, and there is  a method:

```
@Override
    public List<Country> getCoutriesNames() {

        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query<Country> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("SELECT countryName FROM Country");

        List<Country> countriesNames = theQuery.getResultList();

        return countriesNames;
    }
```

So in the and, in this drop down list I get only `countryName`, not the whole `Country` object. This approach requires to create methods in `HopControler`, `CountryService`, `CountryServiceImp`, `CountryDao` and `CountryDaoImp` - just to get one field.

My question: is there any simplier way (maybe in JSP page) to get just `countryName`for this drop down list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I feel your pain, but unfortunately this is the recommended way to implement it.

Of course your can always create a new method in the Dao to return a `List<String>` but why bother. In the future your might need another property like for example the Country id or the Land code (us, es, fr, etc..) in your select.

Of course your can always make the methods shorter like of example:

```
@Override
    public List<Country> getCoutriesNames() {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT countryName FROM Country").getResultList();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification